# How to extract substring from string in PHP until it reaches a different character?

Tags: php, string, substring

For example my string is this:

```
$str = "aaababca";
```

I want to get a substring that stops when it reaches **b** so I would get

```
aaa
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why can't you just iterate over the string? (is the codification the issue?)

Comment: @Theraot they can, but the overhead will be huge.

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko well, regex for this case seems as overhead to me. Although I guess it is optimized C code or something like that.

Comment: @Theraot I was thinking strpos :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that `"b"` is the different character, you have a very simple solution:

```
$substring = strstr($str, "b", true);
```

Otherwise you may loop through the string until you find a different character from the first one:

```
$len = strlen($str);
$substring = $str[0];
$i = 1;
while($i < $len && $str[$i] == $str[0]){
$substring .= $str[$i];
$i++;
}
```

With a fewer lines of code, regular expressions can do exactly the same thing:

```
preg_match("/^([[:print:]])\\1+/", $str, $mat);
$substring = $mat[0];
```